# Drools Rulesengine - Objects in Memory vs Rules to Tidy Them

Tags: drools

In Drools, is it better to leave declared objects in working memory, or delete them as soon as they are finished with.

A simplified rule file as an example (with assumptions that objects have been declared, etc)

`rule "get red results"
when
  AllResults
then
  /* get red results from AllResults */
  insert(new RedResults)
end`

rule "get blue results"
when
  AllResults
then
  /* get blue results from AllResults */
  insert(new BlueResults)
end

/* is this rule best-practice or does it increase session execution time */
rule "remove AllResults as no longer needed"
when
  RedResults
  BlueResults
  AllResults
then
  delete(AllResults)
end

The solution I am working on is focused on speed so if one method of handling objects provides faster rule running, that would be preferential.

I'm inclined to think that adding extra rules to clean up working memory will just add to the full completion time of the whole session, but if the working memory is "cleaner" does that mean additional rules run faster?

I appreciate there is most likely very low-level ways to address these, I'm just after a more general best-practice answer.
I'm also aware a lot of questions like this do depend heavily on the solution itself (of which I have been purposely vague) but I can try to provide some more info on it if possible.